# Can Hyper-V gracefully handle iSCSI interruptions?

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi

My Hyper-V machine stores its VM disks on an iSCSI volume located on a Synology DiskStation.

Occasionally (once a month) the DiskStation will restart itself for firmware and package updates, this causes an interruption to the iSCSI services and Hyper-V moves to kill the VM instances, reporting being unable to access the VM configuration.

Is there a way to configure Hyper-V to instead immediately pause a VM and wait for iSCSI connectivity to resume instead of killing the VMs?

Comment: Dont fair for corruption to update firmware while the VM run ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a particularly good idea to me to allow your VM storage platform to automatically update and restart itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Windows Server 2016, still in preview.  Earlier versions of Windows Server can't do what you're asking.

Comment: And 2016 you can have in 2 months or so, so the solution is not "far" out.